# Textbook / Reports on Alphanomics

Tags: reference-request

Look at ACCT 340 @ http://www.gsb.stanford.edu/research/courses/acctg.html

I've read some of the research papers written by the Professor, and the material is very interesting. However, I'm looking for more in-depth, deeper examples (i.e. not only the theory, but also practical examples.)

Is there any good textbook / technical report on this material?

Comment: You should ask the Prof for recommendations.

Comment: check google scholar i saw a few papers there